# Asp.net webservice method using post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, http, post

I have created a web service method using the HTTP `get` method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void logindata()
{   
    string abc = "{\"Successfull\":\"1\"}";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType ="text/HTML";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(abc);
}
```

How do I change this method so that it uses `post` instead?

Comment: Unrelated: the content-type should be `application/json`.

Comment: I have done it but how to make it using post method.

Comment: Do you need $.AJAX post method to call this "logindata" web service?

Comment: By Default  WebMethod is of Post Type. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: How to use $.Ajax post method in webservice or asmx file